# How do I customize website CSS in a react native webview?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webview

I've been playing around with webviews on react native, but I would like to change the website's css to customize the style. Is there a way to do it?

Using react native cli & android studio

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, StatusBar, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, WebView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

class king_of_prussia extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
       title: 'King Of Prussia',
       headerTitleStyle :{textAlign: 'center', alignSelf:'center', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'normal', color: '#3E3E40' },
       headerStyle:{
           backgroundColor:'white',
       },
   };

  ActivityIndicatorLoadingView() {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        color='black'
        size='large'
        style={styles.ActivityIndicatorStyle}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
            backgroundColor='#F1F1F1'
            barStyle='dark-content'/>
            <WebView
                source={{uri: 'https://www.simon.com/mall/king-of-prussia/map#/'}}
                scalesPageToFit = {false}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
                startInLoadingState={true}
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

export default king_of_prussia;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#EFF2F5',
  },
  footer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 25,
  },
  shareText:{
    color:'#95989A',
    fontSize: 12
  },
  ActivityIndicatorStyle:{
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

[image]

I would like to remove the header from the website as well as modifying other styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebView has an "injectedJavaScript" prop available which would allow you to feed it a block of javascript that you could use to manipulate any CSS/HTML on the page.

It's a bit hacky, but I didn't really see an alternative since you're essentially working with an iframe when using a webview.

I'm using this to hide the burger bar in the navbar of a site I reference in a webview in my app:

```
<WebView
  source={{uri: this.state.magicUrl}}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  injectedJavaScript={'function hideHeaderToggle() {var headerToggle = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-toggle"), i;for (i = 0; i < headerToggle.length; i += 1) {headerToggle[i].style.display = "none";};}; hideHeaderToggle();'}
/>
```

Entirely possible that there are better alternatives out there, but this certainly would be one option.

Comment: Devon Gardner thanks a lot! do you know how can I give 100% height to the map?

Comment: function fullMap() {
  var topNav = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');
  var mapWrap = document.getElementsByClassName('map-wrapper');
  for(var i = 0; i < topNav.length; i += 1){
    topNav[i].style.display = "none";
  };
  for(var i = 0; i < mapWrap.length; i += 1){
    mapWrap[i].style.height = "100%";
    mapWrap[i].style.top = "0"
  };
}
fullMap();

Comment: Sorry about the format, comment formatting sucks. Pass that whole thing as a string into injectedJavaScript and it should be golden.

Comment: One last thing, the top = "0" worked, however, the height keeps the same, any idea?

Comment: Tough to say, lots of potential points of failure when dealing with all the css and js probably running on the site's side. That said, you should be able to play around with the attributes in the second for loop to manipulate the map-wrapper element however you need. May want to try playing around with some additional attributes like position or alternative ways to pass in a height. Maybe add !important to the height value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194252/discussion-between-alberto-ramos-and-devon-gardner).